# ov5642 i2c not detected

Tags: i2c, schematics, camera

We brought the following sensor from Boundary devices.

https://boundarydevices.com/product/nit6x_5mp/

The idea is to add Camera for our i.MX6 Customized board

I connected the following to check whether the board is working or not..

Only connected all the Grounds to Ground and VDDs to 5V and 
SDA to SIOD, SCL to SIOC.
[image]

We have the following header exposed on the board as like Sabrelite.

[image]

i2cdetect on the linux command line did not gave any address. Touching the camera it is very hot.. What I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 V VDD is too high, see the specifications: AVDD =  2.6 to 3 V, DVDD = 1.7 to 3V, and AF_V_CC = 2.6 to 3.3 V.

And of course, if the module still works add the 6 to 27 MHz clock to XCLC input

Please do not edit to add confusion, the pin names are the same as in the data sheet screenshot above.

Comment: Same is the case when I connected 2.5 V as power supply

Comment: Before or after 5V?

Comment: After 5V.......

Comment: Replace the module.

Comment: Do we need any other connections for confirming I2C

Comment: It might still work, add some 6 to 27mhz system clock

Comment: Replacing the module and adding system clock worked..